# SSH Into Whonix Workstation

Tags: configuration, whonix, ssh, connection

Is it technically possible to SSH into a Whonix workstation locally? So if I'm on the same local network as the device running the workstation. For example, my laptop is on 192.168.0.2, the device running the gateway is on 192.168.0.3 and the workstation on 10.152.152.22.

Perhaps SSH into the Whonix Gateway first, then SSH into the workstation? Or maybe some port-forwarding somehow? Can someone assist with this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to SSH from HOST > Gateway > Workstation.

Have you tried these instructions?
https://www.whonix.org/wiki/File_Transfer#SSH_into_Whonix-Gateway

Comment: Hi, thanks for providing an answer to this question, could you also include a brief rundown of what the official documentation states? Answers should generally be more than links so that later if the link location changes or the site is down, the answer will still contain the information, even if the link is no longer valid.